# How do I authorize the adding of a member to a Google group?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-groups

I found this snippet from another thread on this site but the issue was never resolved and I'm following up on it so this is the original thread

```
function addGroupMember(userEmail,groupEmail) {
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: "MEMBER"
  };

  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log("User %s added as a member of group %s.", userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

I changed it to this

```
function onChangeAdd () {
  function addGroupMember(userEmail,groupEmail) {
    var member = {
      email: userEmail,
      role: "MEMBER"
    };

    member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
    Logger.log("User %s added as a member of group %s.", userEmail, groupEmail);
  }

  addGroupMember('andyphu@mnmsa.org', 'mft17287@googlegroups.com');
}
```

But the script has an error where it isn't able to find the group key. From Google's SDK sources I think I have the right key but I don't think I have it authorized on both ends if it's even needed.

I authorized Admin Directory but that's it and I think I have to somehow authorize it with the group but there's no script editor for that so im not sure. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

### The Directory API works only for users who have a [Google account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926) - see [Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites)

Thus, your code will work perfectly for a group you created for your GSuite domain, but not for a free `@googlegroups.com` group.